# How to get application permission settings in android?

Tags: android, permissions

I am developing a small application which lists only those application which connects to internet. How can I read the android manifest file from the Packageinfo class to access the permission settings of each application programmatically?

```
private void getWebApps() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     PackageManager packageManager=this.getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> applist=packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
        Iterator<PackageInfo> it=applist.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            PackageInfo pk=(PackageInfo)it.next();

            String appname=pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();

            installedapplist.add(appname);

        }
```

In the above code "installedapplist" is an arrayList which stores the apps names. But before adding to the list I need to check only those application which access the internet. Can anyone help me how to check the permission?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use -

```
getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
```

This returns an array of permissions. You could then iterate through it and check if the Internet one exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find that in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions).